# Django and Angular, model id field

Tags: html, angularjs, django, model, django-rest-framework

I've got models made in Django and as I've understood it, they have been automatically assigned an Id.

How can I see what this id is in the console log? When I return objects in angular I don't have access to this id field.

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email')
```

Comment: Add `'id'` to the DRF serializer's field list.  Then it will send this field to the client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ross Rogers said,

Simply add 'id' to the serializer field list like so:

```
class PlayerSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = ('id', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'email')
```